# Why does Luke ignore Yoda's advice?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

In The Empire Strikes Back, Luke asks what he will find in the cave and Yoda responds:

> **Yoda:** *Only what you take with you.*

He follows this up with some very specific advice.

> **Yoda:** *Your weapons, you will not need them.*

**But Luke ignores him and takes his weapon belt with him. Why?**

Comment: "Evil will always triumph because good is dumb." - Dark Helmet

Comment: Vote to close, move to parenting stack exchange. They're much better at dealing with teenagers who don't listen.

Comment: @R.M.: Good will always triumph over evil, because good has dumb luck.

Comment: Was this scene in the initial release?  The only part that rings a bell is Luke jumping about with Yoda on his back.

Comment: I remember being freaked out by this scene as a kid in the mid-'90s, and it seems that [Wikipedia provides no evidence showing that my memory is wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases#The_Empire_Strikes_Back).

Comment: In Luke's defense, he phrased that as more of a suggestion.

Comment: By “initial release” I mean what I saw in 1980, not what @errantlinguist saw in 199x.  There's some evidence that Lucas fiddled with the movies between those dates.  (I don't know when I last saw any of IV–VI other than fragments.)

Comment: @AntonSherwood, that's interesting: It's not surprising that Lucas had already begun fiddling with the movies, but it is that someone hasn't documented them. Still, Lucas seems to find inspiration in Stalin when it comes to rewriting (erasing) history...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is another example of [Luke's lack of belief in himself and in the power of the Force](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F15dgBzwOrc) and the potential for him to fall to the Dark Side. When faced with evil, he seeks to confront that evil with force (small f) rather than allying himself with the Force (big F) to help him.

The film's official novelisation makes his thought process rather clearer

> *“Your weapon,” Yoda reproved. “You won’t need it.”*
>
> *Luke paused and looked again at the tree. **Go into that evil cave
>   completely unarmed? As skilled as Luke was becoming, he did not feel
>   quite equal to that test.** He gripped his saber tighter and shook his
>   head.*
>
> *Yoda shrugged and placidly gnawed his Gimer Stick.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Empire Strikes Back - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: I can see that, that is what I was trying to aks. UV for the help and the answer

Comment: @KyloRen - Now ask the question about Obi-Wan viewing the security footage :-)

Comment: tighter!  more tightly....

Comment: @JoeBlow - Oh, that's far from the worst part of this novel.

Comment: heh I bet!  cheers ...

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the quote. It shows that Luke is *afraid*. This makes a great deal more sense, as the entire cave is full of the Dark side and Luke's fears manifest there.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Clearly he's afraid. The issue at hand is how he chooses to *confront* that fear. Yoda advises him to trust the Force. Luke decides that he'd rather trust his weapons.

Comment: “Fear is the path to the dark side. Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.”

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/53/e4/e6/53e4e6129177ea884a7f0063c07172cb.jpg

Comment: Well, luke DOES use dark side a couple times in the movies if I remember correctly.

One time he uses force-choke on two guards.

The other time is when fighting darth vader, where seemly he pulls some Mace-Windy-style fighting and let his rage fuel his strength, and then he tires out Darth Vader with pure raw power.

Comment: @speeder - Using the dark side isn't safe. It leads to using it more which eventually leads to you standing over the corpses of children.

Comment: Well... that didn't stopped a bunch of jedi, including a couple that DID ended falling... If you count the EU then, it overflows with this (and also overflows with Jedi desperate to not fall, while at the same time needing to use DS powers to succeed in first place).

Still, my point was: Luke is very Anakin-like, and is all too happy not only to use DS powers sometimes, but also to have fear, love, ignore orders from superiors, and so on... basically Luke is a Anakin that "won" fast enough to not fall. (and then 'caused', or thinks he 'caused' the fall of Kylo Ren)

Comment: Correction, @Valorum: Using the dark side isn't safe... unless your name is Kyle Katarn. ;P